# Communication between winros and ros on ubuntu

Tags: ros, win-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to implement communication between win_ros and ros on ubuntu. I followed win_ros tutorials, but it seems a little bit confusing.
And when i create a node on win_ros, there are some errors. Someone has experience about it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/158156/communication-between-winros-and-ros-on-ubuntu/) by [Qt_Yeung](https://answers.ros.org/users/13976/qt_yeung/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2014-04-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kamiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5346/kamiccolo/) on 2014-04-29**:
Could You please specify those errors? There are no magicians here :} Also, which ROS version are You using?

**Comment by [Qt_Yeung](https://answers.ros.org/users/13976/qt_yeung/) on 2014-04-30**:
I install Fuerte both on ubuntu and windows. For win_ros, I just followed this page http://wiki.ros.org/win_ros/Msvc%20SDK%20Projects%20-%20Fuerte.  But now  I don't know how to create ros node on window, which can send messages to roscore on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In case of Fuerte, a demo solution is installed with the sdk into C:\opt\rosws\fuerte\sdk-tutorials. Before run env.bat(or setup.bat), set ROS_MASTER_URI into setup.bat with IP address of ubuntu machine where roscore is running.

```
set ROS_MASTER_URI=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:11311
```

---

Originally posted by [Yeongil Choe](https://answers.ros.org/users/4499/yeongil-choe/) with karma: 16 on 2014-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Qt_Yeung](https://answers.ros.org/users/13976/qt_yeung/) on 2014-05-14**:
Thanks! It works now. I changed that environment variable, then it runs.